# Are there any javascript libraries for interface introduction/tutorials

Tags: javascript

I would like to know if there are any javascript projects which help to give a "tour" 
within a new web interface.

E.g. when Google changes interfaces in popular apps like gmail or maps you usually have the option, when you visit the first time, to see tipps/hints/videos etc. what you can do where.
Some Android/iOs Apps do this kind of introduction as well.

I would expect, that you could maybe define some events, that need to be triggered until you get to the next step and other events that trigger notifications/popups of any sort.

I found it hard to google for such functionality. Maybe this doesn't exist and I need to write it from scratch

Comment: You say "I need to write it from scratch" like that's a bad thing...

Comment: nah I just don't want to reinvent the wheel :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several:

- [Intro.js](http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/)
- [Bootstrap Tour](http://bootstraptour.com/)
- [Joyride](http://zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin)
- [Hopscotch](http://linkedin.github.io/hopscotch/)
- [Pageguide](http://tracelytics.github.io/pageguide/)

Found that list [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-product-tours-intro-js/).

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend:

- http://bootstraptour.com/
- http://revaxarts-themes.com/tour/

Both are easy to use and good explaind :)

Comment: [Link only posts are normally frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65277/are-link-only-answers-poor-practice).  Next time, try and add some explanations in the answer.